# How can I stop wp_nav_menu from returning extraneous root links?

Tags: menus

[image]because the 1st menu element is returning two links I get a double box for the 1st menu item, which is super annoying.

Is there a way to stop this double link output either with a WordPress option, or a passed argument to `wp_nav_menu()`? Here is my template:

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <div class="container">

    <!-- site header -->
    <header class="site-header">
        <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url();?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
        <h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5> 

        <?php
            $args = array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary'
            );      
        ?>

        <nav class="site-nav">
            <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
        </nav>

    </header>
    <!-- /site-header -->
```

The template above generates the following HTML:

```
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="menu-primary-container">
        <ul class="menu" id="menu-primary">
             <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23" id="menu-item-23">
                 <a href="http://localhost">
                 <a href="http://localhost/my-account/">My Account</a>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

functions.php

```
    function joditheme_resources() {

    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'joditheme_resources');

    // Navigation Menus
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu'),
        'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu'),
    ));
```

index.php

```
    <?php

    get_header();

    if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="post">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </article>

<?php endwhile;

else :
    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

endif;

    get_footer();
```

Comment: It's pretty tough to say based on the info posted. This isn't normal WordPress behavior though. Do you have some kind of JavaScript tab thing going on? (Try disabling JS temporarily to rule that out). Also search plugin/theme code for use of the `wp_nav_menu_args` filter which could be altering the arguments passed to `wp_nav_menu` (perhaps something funky is going on with a custom walker class.

Comment: @JodiSolbrig how is the menu for the `'primary'` theme location set up in the menu management page (Appearance > Menus) in the dashboard? Also, the output HTML does not match the template code you posted at all - the header elements don't appear to be printed, and you show a closing `</nav>` tag with no respective opening one... Are you sure WordPress is actually using the template you posted?

Comment: @dave-romsey Thanks for the tips, I'm not up to speed on javascript. I'm starting out learning PHP and Wordpress, haven't progressed to JS yet, but plan to shortly.

Comment: @bosco The setup appears to be pretty standard. I've been following a wordpress theme creation tutorial. I created the 'primary' menu locations in functions.php using the following code: // Navigation Menus
register_nav_menus(array(
 'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu'),
 'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu'),
));

Comment: What's really strange, is that when I call the "wp_nav_menu ( $args )" from anywhere else in the header, like after the BODY tag, etc. It works normally. I get one HREF per menu link.

Comment: you are viewing that in INSPECT.. Youd better to go to page SOURCE and copy the part from there. I think there will be different `<a>` codes, than what we see in INSPECT

Answer (score -1):

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo home_url();?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
```

Soooo I forgot to close my link tag in my header. Deeerp. Lol

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo home_url();?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> </a> </h1>
```

closing the tag fixes the issue.